# How to convert a Bitmap to Drawable in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

How can I convert a Bitmap image to Drawable ?

Comment: Hi i got the answer of your question follow this link and got the right answer i do it.
and i success,i hope you got the success.
best of luck http://www.androidsnippets.com/convert-bitmap-to-drawable

Comment: Contribution is a great way to say thanx... :) Contributions in terms of giving answers... :)

Comment: @Farhan k    ...... .

Answer (score 283, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [`BitmapDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)

From the documentation:

> A `Drawable` that wraps a bitmap and can
>   be tiled, stretched, or aligned. You
>   can create a `BitmapDrawable` from a
>   file path, an input stream, through
>   XML inflation, or from a `Bitmap`
>   object.

Comment: @Deprecated Use BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap) to ensure that the drawable has correctly set its target density.

Answer (score 890):

Try this it converts a `Bitmap` type image to `Drawable`

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Answer (score 163):

Having seen a large amount of issues with bitmaps incorrectly scaling when converted to a `BitmapDrawable`, the general way to convert should be:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Without the `Resources reference`, the `bitmap` may not render properly, even when scaled correctly. There are numerous questions on here which would be solved simply by using this method rather than a straight call with only the `bitmap` argument.

Comment: At least comment why if you're going to down vote. This is a perfectly valid answer, and brings extra information to solve issues that can occur with the other answers offered. Drawables made directly from a bitmap often have scaling errors without the getResources() reference.

Comment: this is a more accurate answer considering the one from @Manoj is deprecated.

Comment: @Raykud, Manoj's answer and this answer show the same code. And, how it is deprecated? And, how is this accurate if that is deprecated and this too is deprecated(It in real is not deprecated)

Comment: @Sambhav.K because original answer from Manoj was "Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);"   but was edited years later.

Answer (score 35):

Offical Bitmapdrawable [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)

This is sample on how to convert [bitmap to drawable](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/09/convert-bitmap-to-drawable-with.html)

```
Bitmap bitmap;  
//Convert bitmap to drawable
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: sorry...i was not serious

Comment: You could have upvoted instead of writing the same answer.

Answer (score 32):

I used with context

```
//Convert bitmap to drawable
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
```

Comment: Duplicate answer.

Answer (score 23):

**1) bitmap to Drawable  :**

```
Drawable mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
// mImageView.setDrawable(mDrawable);
```

**2) drawable to Bitmap :**

```
Bitmap mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.icon_resource);
// mImageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon);
```

Answer (score 20):

If you have a bitmap image and you want to use it in drawable, like

```
Bitmap contact_pic;    //a picture to show in drawable
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(contact_pic);
```

Comment: That's deprecated now. Use the BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap) constructor now.

Comment: @schlingel It still working fine and many of us are using it in our projects,

Comment: That's good for you, but doesn't help when Google eventually kills this constructor and you have to rewrite everything.

Comment: @schlingel yes, but still some one in rush use this and it make a work

Answer (score 11):

Just do this:

```
private void setImg(ImageView mImageView, Bitmap bitmap) {

    Drawable mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    mImageView.setDrawable(mDrawable);
}
```

Comment: Not the solution for what he is asking

Answer (score 2):

here's another one:

```
Drawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin users:

Kotlin has a function for converting `Bitmap` to `BitmapDrawable`:

`Bitmap.toDrawable(resources)`

Answer (score 0):

convert Bitmap To Drawable in Sketchware app using direct block

```
    android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable d = new android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```