# create drawable from path problem

Tags: android, path, drawable

For some reason d=null when creating a drawable from coverArtURLStr, which is the full http path to the resource on the LAN.
Anything obvious wrong? It's a path to a .png
[I can access the LAN OK, and Data.defaultCoverArt works fine]

```
public static void updateCoverArt(String coverArtURLStr)
{
    String coverArtURL = coverArtURLStr;
    Drawable d;

    if (coverArtURL.equals(""))
        d = Data.defaultCoverArt;
    else           
        d = Drawable.createFromPath(coverArtURL);

    Data.coverArtIV.setImageDrawable(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `Drawable.createFromPath()` method can handle URLs. Try this solution [Android Drawable Images from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3375166/170842).