# Downloading image from URL with spaces in the path in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to download image from the path. 
This is my code:

```
String urlString = "http://www.hospimedica.com/images/stories/articles/article_images/_CC/20110328 - DJB146.gif";
url = new URL(urlString.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

But it returns me null in bm. Any ideas how to make this code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces are not the problem ... I tried it with your url and it's working

```
try {
    String urlString = "http://www.hospimedica.com/images/stories/articles/article_images/_CC/20110328 - DJB146.gif";
    URL url = new URL(urlString.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));

    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
    connection.connect();

    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

    Log.d("#####", "result: " + BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The important line is `connection.setRequestProperty("User-agent", "Mozilla/4.0");`
I don't know why that solves it, but it has obviously worked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url).

Comment: That's a hack and not a solution. The generic solution (escape any "problematic" character) is provided by CaseyB

Comment: Unfortunately `URLEncoder.encode()` "encodes" the string to `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hospimedica.com%2Fimages%2Fstories%2Farticles%2Farticle_images%2F_CC%2F20110328+-+DJB146.gif` which throws a MalformedURLException...
Maybe I didn't post the best solution, at least I tested it before I did ...

Comment: Btw. the URL is not the problem .. like I said in the first line of my answer. The link I posted shows another question regarding that problem, without even mentioning the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Try `UrlEncoder`.

```
String urlString = URLEncoder.encode("http://www.hospimedica.com/images/stories/articles/article_images/_CC/20110328 - DJB146.gif");
url = new URL(urlString);
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```