# Why Image file not found in android on server but open in browser

Tags: java, android, http

I am trying to download image from server. Few are downloading and few and creating problem. I don't know why.

I have downloaded and show image to user on the same location. Here is the file which is able to download.

> http://www.mongreldog.co.nz/unilogo/Backgrounds_20399.png

When I am trying to download following image. **This image is opening in browser but not downloading in android**

> http://www.mongreldog.co.nz/unilogo/Twitter-Ryan_Giggs_Imogen_Thomas_Guard-Footballer_Affair_UK_Manchester%20United_M_785.jpg
>
> Its give exception
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.mongreldog.co.nz/unilogo/Twitter-Ryan_Giggs_Imogen_Thomas_Guard-Footballer_Affair_UK_Manchester United_M_785.jpg
>   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
>   at src.com.mongreldog.appsupport.Utils.downloadImage(Utils.java:77)
>   at src.com.mongreldog.ViewFullCompAndCommentActivity$3.performInBackground(ViewFullCompAndCommentActivity.java:607)
>   at src.com.mongreldog.appsupport.HeavyWorker.doInBackground(HeavyWorker.java:44)
>   at src.com.mongreldog.appsupport.HeavyWorker.doInBackground(HeavyWorker.java:1)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)

Here is my code.

```
public static Bitmap downloadImage(String imageURLStr) {


        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageURLStr);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            in = conn.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            bitmap = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            bitmap = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bitmap = null;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bitmap = null;
        }
        return bitmap;

}
```

Comment: are you sure that all are having same resolution...?

Comment: how you call this method (means where to call and how)?

Answer (score 1):

Use URL Encoder to encode the image `URL`, as you can see the `URL` have white spaces in the log report.

```
public static Bitmap downloadImage(String imageURLStr) {
      imageURLStr  = URLEncoder.encode(imageURLStr, "utf-8");
      //... rest of your code.
}
```

---

**Edit**: as you reported of issue '+' instead of %20

you can use

```
public static Bitmap downloadImage(String imageURLStr) {
          imageURLStr  = imageURLStr.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
          //... rest of your code.
}
```

For source check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5818684/593709)

Comment: you are right there are specs. I am trying to use your code but it replace the " " with "+". But it should be "%20".

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I just try "Uri.encode()" by Nabeel answer. And its working. The above solution for replaceAll() is not look goods to me.

Answer (score 1):

I try to use `URLEncoder.encode()` to encode the `URL`. Its strange that it convert `" "` with `"+"`.

Please try `Uri.encode(imageURL)`. I just try it and its working perfectly.

I have tested that in android.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file name is not being parsed correctly (the space between 'Manchester' and 'United').

Use `URLEncoder.encode()` to encode the URL.

Comment: Same issue. I am trying to use your code but it replace the " " with "+". But it should be "%20"

Answer (score 0):

Your second URL is very instable. It may return 404 in the most cases even in Chome. I have seen the picture only once.