# Too many images in android app

Tags: android

In my android app i have got something like 70-80 images. This is making my app very heavy. What are my options to reduce the size without loing any image. I mean any way to compress them or anything like that?

Comment: What format of images are you using, PNG, JPG, GIF?

Answer (score 4):

Try storing them in the database,

https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html

Answer (score 0):

krio's answer is probably a pretty good way to go.
If you're looking for alternatives, you can zip resources and assets, and then pull them out of the zip on demand when you need them.
I'm not sure how much extra compression that'll give you over the APK compression (and obviously you'll need to add in the time to pull the file out of the zip). Will only 80 or so files, the time to parse through the zip file and pull a file out should be fairly small.

Comment: I will give both a try..the Zip and the sqllite idea. Is there a way where I can download my images directly into the drawable folder from a website/Url?

Comment: Might be worth having a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url