# android - images not showing on device from url

Tags: android, image, url, drawable

I am receiving images from a URL and they display on the emulator but when I use a device the default image is shown. Im not totally sure which part of the code you require so Ill add more on request:

```
pubImage = extras.getString("pubImage");

ImageView ivimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
try{
            ivimage.setImageDrawable(grabImageDrawableFromUrl(pubImage));
            Log.d(TAG, pubImage);   

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [Prime](https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime) for all of my image loading in Android. If you were using it then you would not have to worry about issues like this.

Comment: Nice Self Promotion :-).. tried using it now.. But find the image a lot more scaled down than needed.Is there a way to give out required height, width in the API..

Comment: If your using the RemoteImageView then make sure to set it to whatever size you require, outside of that I have never seen any issues whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the package.Looks good but just got an out of memory error. Let me try to work on that

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
ivimage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

if you still not get solution then use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url), it seems as if you might be missing a few details, but perhaps you should paste `grabImageDrawableFromUrl()` either way.