# How to set image button resource from web url in Android?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an image button and would like to set background image from internet URL. I don't want to save background picture into SD card instead my image button's image needs to be URL. How can I do that in Android

Comment: You need to download it into a bitmap variable, and then set it as background image. Android is not a browser in which you could do that functionality you'd like to achieve.

Comment: i think your answer is here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android

Comment: @MudassarShaheen i think one comment is enough of same Link :)

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this but hope fully this will work with you

```
private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, saveFilename);
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and for image view

```
ImageView IV= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageId);      
Drawable drw = ImageOperations(this,url,filename)
IV.setBackgroundDrawable(drw)
```

get URL

```
    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {

    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        Bitmap bitmap;
class loadImage extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        URL url = new URL(stringURL);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(),
                url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uri
                .toURL().openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        byte[] img = byteBuffer.toByteArray();
        byteBuffer.flush();
        byteBuffer.close();
        input.close();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ImageButton image_btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.your_image_button_id);
        image_btn.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download your Image as Drawable: 
[Android Drawable Images from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url)

and after that set it as background drawable

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)
```