# how do i display an image from a certain URL in my android app?

Tags: android, image, url, curl

I am making an app and I would like to keep the images updated when I change them. I am not sure how to display an image from a specific URL.

any help and suggestions is appreciated

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url?rq=1

Comment: I'd see a huge difference between "keeping images updated" and "displaying images from a URL".

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate, as mentioned before, but still, I'd use an AsyncTask to load an image from an URL (which doesn't seems to be the case in the provided links).

Something along these lines:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>() {
  @Override 
  protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
    Drawable result = null;
    try {
      URL url = new URL(params[0]);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.connect();
      InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
      result = Drawable.createFromStream(input, "src");
    } catch (MalformedURLException muExp) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Bad URL provided!", muExp);
    } catch (IOException ioExp) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error loading content from URL!", ioExp);
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
    // Do something with your Drawable, in UI, here...
  }
}.execute("http://myimageurl.com/image.jpg");
```