# How to retrieve base64 encoded JSON to Android

Tags: android, json, getjson

How to retrieve the image_url from json to android.json code is here. I just want to get the image to a button.

```
{
    "page_menu": {
        "flag": "M"
    },
    "menu": [
        {
            "pid": "0",
            "name": "Home",
            "refid": "1",
            "image_url": "aG9tZS5wbmc=",
            "ord_field": "1"
        },
        {
            "pid": "0",
            "name": "About Us",
            "refid": "2",
            "image_url": "YWJvdXQucG5n",
            "ord_field": "2"
        },
        {
            "pid": "0",
            "name": "Services",
            "refid": "3",
            "image_url": "c2VydmljZTIucG5n",
            "ord_field": "3"
        },
        {
            "pid": "0",
            "name": "Products",
            "refid": "4",
            "image_url": "cHJvZHVjdHMucG5n",
            "ord_field": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

here is my  code for retrieve the  json values, i did any mistakes ?? now also am not getting image

```
JSONArray jsonMainNode1 = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("menu");
              int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode1.length(); 
               for(int i=0; i <lengthJsonArr; i++)
              {                                     
                  JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode1.getJSONObject(i);

                      String Pid      = jsonChildNode.optString("pid".toString());
                      String Name     = jsonChildNode.optString("name").toString();
                      String Refid=jsonChildNode.optString("refid".toString());

                      String image     = jsonChildNode.getString("image_url");

                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                  Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);

                ImageView ima=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
              ima.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);

                      OutputData = Name+ima;
```

result is Home android.widget.imageview{4176f0c8VED..ID 0,0-0,0} like these..

my php code is here..

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    $json['page_menu']['flag'] = 'M';
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $json['menu'][$i]['pid']=ucwords($row['pid']);
        $json['menu'][$i]['name']=$row['name'];
        $json['menu'][$i]['refid']=$row['refid'];
        $json['menu'][$i]['image_url']=base64_encode($row['image_url']);
        $json['menu'][$i++]['ord_field']=$row['ord_field'];

    }
```

Comment: Do you able to parse the response?

Comment: yes, i am getting the string only in my button not image

Comment: String means? Hv you getting the value for attribute image_url in your object? and if yes then is it base64 or imageUrl?

Comment: am getting the value base 64.

Comment: @Rashmi i tried and i posted my code.please check.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you able to parse the json and u got the value of image_url attribute from your json in base 64 format

Convert your base 64 string to image as

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, ecodedString.length);
```

and set it to imageView as

```
image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

Comment: You cannot directly give image url in decodeByteArray(); First parameter should be the byte array of image not byte array of URL. By the way I am not the person who down voted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(respponse);

JSONArray arr = obj.GetJSONArray("menu");

JSONObject data = arr.GetJSONObject(0);

String image_url = data.GetString("image_url");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly give image url in decodeByteArray(); First parameter should be the byte array of image not byte array of URL.

Please check the documentation.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[], int, int)

Check the below links to load image from url
[Android load from URL to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992964/android-load-from-url-to-bitmap)
[Android Drawable Images from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url?lq=1)

Comment: i didnt use any url, image_url is my table column name,i stored my image.png ,then i encoded in json.