# How to display image from url

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have image in server url then i'm passing and displaying in to Card. I have done this in android using LoaderImageView library and displaying but in Glass i'm passing the url link to card. But i got this error "The method addImage(Drawable) in the type CardBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Code:

```
 public static Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url)  {
        Bitmap x;


        try {
             HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
             connection.connect();
             InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

             x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
             return new BitmapDrawable(x);

             } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            //Do something with the exception.
        }

        catch(IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
       }
        return null;

    }


    View view = new CardBuilder(getBaseContext(), CardBuilder.Layout.TITLE)
    .setText("TITLE Card")
    // .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_phone)
    .addImage(drawableFromUrl(link))
    .getView();
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the doc](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardBuilder), addImage takes Drawable, int, or Bitmap. It doesn't take String.

You can download image using AsyncTask or thread or whatever you like and convert it to Drawable. Then, you can call addImage.

For example:

```
// new DownloadImageTask().execute("your url...")

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {     
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        return drawableFromUrl(url);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        // yourCardBuilder.addImage(link)
        // or start another activity and use the image there...
    }
}

public static Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    Bitmap x;
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return new BitmapDrawable(x);
}
```

**I haven't tested the code but hope you get the idea.**

Also see:

- [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)
- [Android Drawable Images from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url)

**Edit:**

```
private Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) {
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {

    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        return drawableFromUrl(url);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        stopSlider();
        if(result != null) {
            mCardAdapter.setCards(createCard(getBaseContext(), result));
            mCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

See my full example on [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/prt2121/LoadImage). [SliderActivity](https://github.com/prt2121/LoadImage/blob/master/glass/src/main/java/com/prt2121/slider/SliderActivity.java) might be helpful for you.

Comment: Getting error on Unhandled exception type IOException