# Ressource not found after upgrade to Mvvmcross 6.0.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an xamarin forms application using MvvmCross 5.7.0. Here everything works. when I Upgrade to 6.0.1 I get this exception in my custom renderer for the bottom navigation bar when the first navigation after the splash screen is triggered.

```
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

When I use a default MvxTabbedPage I get this message:

```
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

My Style hasn't changed during the upgrade and is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_gray</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And the style is applied on my main activity with this:

```
[Activity(Label = "MoneyFox", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

The project is open source and you can find it under this link: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/tree/mvvmCrossUpdate

What can this be?

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598105/android-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x0) may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There where two issues. One was that I had wrong Icons set on the pages. The other is an issue with the floating action button I use (see here:  https://github.com/SuavePirate/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.FloatingActionButton/issues/21)