# Image Manager - convert a URI from Google Play Game Services to a Drawable

Tags: android, uri, google-play-games

I am getting the URI from google with this method:

```
Player me = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleApiClient);
Uri uri = me.getHiResImageUri();
```

I read in various posts that because of Google's security restrictions I need to use the `ImageManager` class.

This class only provides voids which directly set the URI as the drawable for the ImageView I provide. This is the method: `loadImage(ImageView imageView, Uri uri);`

The problem is that I need to get a variable of the `Drawable` class from this Uri and use that. Having the Uri set as the drawable of the image does not work in my specific case.
I don't know if there is a class similar to `ImageManager` or if there is a workaround to get the drawable.

Thanks for all replies in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use HttpURLConnection and call the URL, you'll then get the `InputStream` and use it to instantiate a `BitMap` by decoding it thru `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`. As indicated by @señor-reginold-francis in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url), don't forget to add the "User-agent" property as it may be denied access if its absent (considering you're getting it from a google domain)

Answer (score 0):

You still have to determine yourself what you want to do with the image.

```
final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ImageManager.create(context)
    .loadImage(new ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoaded(Uri uri, Drawable drawable, boolean b) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }
}, participant.getHiResImageUri(), R.drawable.placeholder);
```