# Set Linear layout background dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I wanted to set Linear Layout background dynamically in the following way:

1. Fetch image from web url through XML parsing and then store that image into sd card.
2. Now the image saved into sd card.
3. Set that image as a linear layout background in the app.

Now I am stuck in the third step. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=312

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use this:

```
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmImg);
linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Also check this: [How to convert a Bitmap to Drawable in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android)

Comment: am not saving my image into byte array.am saving it like InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
               
               Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
               
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 
                bmImg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, fos);
                
                fos.flush(); 
                fos.close();

Comment: In this case use this:

`bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);`
`BitmaBitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmImg);`
`linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(background);`

Comment: no its not working ,it still showing me null pointer exception

Comment: Are you sure the image is being downloaded and saved properly? Does it exist?

Comment: yes i can see the image at sd card,I dnt know wheres the problem in the code

Comment: Well it's hard to tell what went wrong. Try to add `bmImg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, fos);` before creating `BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmImg);`

Comment: yes,thank you now it is showing me the background image..thanx alot

Comment: This require API 16. Is there other way for lower API?

Comment: As far as I recall this doesn't require API 16.

Comment: BitmapDrawable is deprecated.

Comment: `new BitmapDrawable(bmImg)` is deprecated. Use `new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), bmImg)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I have done this way:

```
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
```

**onCreate**:

```
relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

new LoadBackground("http://www.tmonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/androidfigure.jpg",
            "androidfigure").execute();
```

**AsyncTask** to **load** image in **background**:

```
private class LoadBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {

    private String imageUrl , imageName;

    public LoadBackground(String url, String file_name) {
        this.imageUrl = url;
        this.imageName = file_name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(this.imageUrl);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, this.imageName);
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    private Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(result);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way:

```
BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable("/sdcard/data/image.jpg");
linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 4):

API are deprecated you can use the below code

```
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapImage);
linearLayout.setBackground(background);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
BitmapDrawable bmpBackground = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmpOriginal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @Deimos's answer, but like this since some methods are deprecated now

```
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmImg);
linearLayout.setBackground(background);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also set image from drawable folder.

```
yourView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.FILENAME);
```

That set FILENAME as background image.