# how set a background image of the layout via Url in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

In my application to set background of layout from web url through the JSON. But in image view I am setting like this

```
try {
                  ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.animation);
                  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://alpharithm.in/manager/test/img/files/products/mushroom-soup.jpg").getContent());
                  i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Not to set as a background. How can I set a background for the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get reference form this.

[Set Linear Layout Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646766/set-linear-layout-background-dynamically)

Hope this will be helpfull to you.