# Downloading many pictures from a server in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-image

I don't know how to get several images from a URL.

Those images come in as Bitmap; I need to convert them to drawable, but I don't know how.

> Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

Am I doing it correctly calling the `url(images)`, or is there a better way to do that?

---

**This is the asynctask where I get the images**

```
 private class BajarImagenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

         return BajarImagen(urls[0]);
        }

         protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){       

         Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

                point.setImage(d);


         }
     }
```

This the connection:

```
 private Bitmap BajarImagen (String URL)
        {

         Bitmap bitmap  = null;
         InputStream in = null;
         try {
             in=OpenHttpConnection(URL);
             bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
             in.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e1) {

         }

         return bitmap;
        }
```

**Here is the method with a "FOR" inside to get several URLs and calling many times the asynctask**

```
 public void datosDesdeElXML(String[][] datos) {


    for(int i = 0; i < moteles.length;i++){


        String motel[] = moteles[i];


        double lat = Double.valueOf(motel[0].trim());
        double lng = Double.valueOf(motel[1].trim());

        String name = motel[2].trim();
        String address = motel[3].trim();
        **String urldefotoglobo = motel[4].trim();**
      // here i get url from server in a xml format


        String aidis = motel[5].trim();

        **new BajarImagenTask().execute(urldefotoglobo);**
         // Here i call the asynctask 
          }
      }
```

Comment: Sorry, I know this isn't an answer: using an AsyncTask to do this is just going to be a headache.  I really suggest you look into an architecture based on a Service.

Comment: What do you mean "Architecture based on a Service"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html  It is a much better way to do off-device tasks.