# Converting bitmap to drawable in Android

Tags: android

I'm downloading the image from server and storing it in bitmap object. I want to set this image as background for button. But the button doesn't have the property setImageBitmap. So is there anyway I can set the background of button with the downloaded bitmap image? Like by converting the bitmap to drawable? Sorry, I'm new to Android, please bear with my mistakes (if any).

P.S : I want to use button control only. Because I want some text at the bottom of each buttons and I'm creating these buttons dynamically.

Comment: Convert your `Bitmap` to `BimapDrawable`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a Bitmap to Drawable in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android)

Answer (score 19):

The best way to convert a `Bitmap` to drawable in android is as follows,

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

where `bitmap` is the name the `Bitmap`. Then set the drawable as your `Button` background as follows,

```
btn.setBackground(drawable);
```

**N.B:** Without specifying `getResources()` as the first argument, you may experience inconsistent image sizing across different screen densities.

for more info refer this 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html).

```
Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(contact_pic);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `Bitmap` to `BitmapDrawable` like this

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),your_bitmap);
```

and then set it as background to button as ,

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

**P.S.** You can also do the same inline as ,

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),your_bitmap));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it, I've used several times:

```
Drawable drawable = (Drawable)new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap);    
Button button= new Button(this);    
button.setBackground(drawable);
```

Comment: setBackground method is only available from API level 16.

Comment: How can I use the converted drawable in  setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int) method? Because it takes all int parametres.