# Set image loaded from URL as wallpaper

Tags: android, url, button, wallpaper, picasso

I'm using Picasso in my app and I managed to open the image in a fullscreen view when the user taps it. Now I would like a button which overlays the image and that sets the image as wallpaper. 
All images are loaded from URL and stored in a remote server.

I don't know how to achieve this since I'm a veeeery beginner. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: i simplified my answer code, just in case you found it more complex at the first time

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in button onclicklistener to set image as wallpaper

```
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
           wpm.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
            InputStream ins = null;
            try {
                ins = new URL(Imageurl).openStream();

                wpm.setStream(ins);
                Toast.makeText(ImageViewerActivity.this, "successfully set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

use [ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) instead:

```
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT).build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                    ISolaceContext.getAppContext())
                    .discCacheExtraOptions(20, 20, CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, null)
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(Media.options).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    loader.loadImage(url, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

       @Override
       public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                                Bitmap loadedImage) {
          // Now you have the image in your hands as a Bitmap(called: loadedImage) and Now you can do whatever you want with it
          stream.close();
          stream = null;
       }

    });

    loader.clearDiscCache();
    loader.clearMemoryCache();
```

Now you can use the previously generated Bitmap as a background.[converting bitmap to drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android).

Comment: Thank you so much! So do you suggest I should use UIL instead of Picasso?

Comment: @FedericoMoretto yea i think you should use it as it gives you the ability to deal with the resulted bitmap (as it will be loaded into your app) not assigning it directly without having the ability to handle it in a different way

Comment: @JakeWharton it's not my job you don't understand it

Comment: @JakeWharton any suggestion? I have no idea what to do!