# How to display GIF file

Tags: android, gif

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) as a guide to display a 'gif' file. When using the  saved `gif` in `drawable`it display correctly the `gif` I call it like this

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgView1"
    android:src="@drawable/gifFile"
    />
```

but when removing the `src` and tried like initializing the GifImageView in the Activity like this

```
 GifImageView gifFromFile = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
gifFromFile.setImageBitmap(Utils.getBitmapImagefromStorage(context, imageHome));
```

Where `getBitmapImagefromStorage` get the path and `imageHome` gets the filename the gif file doesn't play its only display like an image. It was said that `If given drawable is not a GIF then mentioned Views work like plain ImageView and ImageButton.` But the file I'm providing is a `gif`.I'm wondering if I'm using it correctly.

Also the file can be `png` or `gif` so I needed to support the two.

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: not much aware with library you are using, but you can try this one too : https://github.com/koush/ion

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry i type it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using `GifDrawable`

```
File gifFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
                    .getAbsolutePath(), imageHome);
GifDrawable gifFromPath  = new GifDrawable(gifFile);
```

And then instead of using `setImageBitmap` I use `setImageDrawable`

```
GifImageView gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDealFinder);
        gifImageView.setImageDrawable(gifFromPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GifTextView gifImageView;
```

In onCreate

```
gifImageView = (GifTextView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Call this method in onCreate

```
public void playGif(){
        Animation fadeout = new AlphaAnimation(1.f, 1.f);
        fadeout.setDuration(2500); // You can modify the duration here
        fadeout.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                gifImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gif_image);//your gif file
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        gifImageView.startAnimation(fadeout);
    }
```

In your layout file

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
```

Comment: instead of `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gif_image)`  can I use this `setImageBitmap(Utils.getBitmapImagefromStorage(context, imageHome));`  ?

Comment: I'm having  `Cannot resolve method setImageBitmap`  is there any other way than to use `R.drawable` ?

Comment: Convert your Bitmap to drawable and then set it. Please Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android

Comment: Use Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), yourBitmap);
Then use d as drawable and set it to the imageView

Comment: in `getResources()` I should put the path ?

Comment: No, if you are in an activity just use  getResources()

Comment: how will I call `d` in `setBackgroundResource()`?

Comment: If you are using a drawable directly instead of its id you need to use setBackground() instead of setBackgroundResource(). 

Please use gifImageView.setBackground(d);

Comment: It displays the Gif, but not playing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to work with GIF in your app

```
public class PlayGifView extends View{

     private static final int DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION = 1000;

     private int mMovieResourceId;
     private Movie mMovie;

     private long mMovieStart = 0;
     private int mCurrentAnimationTime = 0;

     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     public PlayGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);

        /**
         * Starting from HONEYCOMB have to turn off HardWare acceleration to draw
         * Movie on Canvas.
         */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
    }

     public void setImageResource(int mvId){
         this.mMovieResourceId = mvId;
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(mMovieResourceId));
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if(mMovie != null){
        setMeasuredDimension(mMovie.width(), mMovie.height());
    }else{
        setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mMovie != null){
        updateAnimtionTime();
        drawGif(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }else{
        drawGif(canvas);
    }
}

private void updateAnimtionTime() {
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (mMovieStart == 0) {
        mMovieStart = now;
    }
    int dur = mMovie.duration();
    if (dur == 0) {
        dur = DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION;
    }
    mCurrentAnimationTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
}

private void drawGif(Canvas canvas) {
    mMovie.setTime(mCurrentAnimationTime);
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
    canvas.restore();
}

}
```

in your activity class

```
PlayGifView pGif = (PlayGifView) findViewById(R.id.viewGif);
pGif.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourgifimage);
```

then in your XML

```
<YourPackageName.PlayGifView
            android:id="@+id/viewGif"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: I m getting this    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Movie.setTime(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at ......drawGif(GifImageView.java:85)

Comment: @RalucaLucaci on which line?